# Do they make a under front car seat wire connector protector

Tags: wiring

under front car drivers seat wire connector protector 2017 Camry LE my dog puppy like to  pull on the wires. has anyone made a cover or anything to protect these venerable connectors to pets, if so please give  a picture thanks you Ron

Comment: You can get puppy & dog seat belts...

Comment: A little bit of tabasco sauce spread over the wires and connectors will not hurt the connectors, but will quickly teach your dog not to pull on them.

Comment: yes around the house it works, but after a few days it dries up and the puppy goes back again? I was thinking of a front to back under the seat flexible piece of sheet plastic ,what do you think?